# When trying to insert a Custom Font in Expo using AppLoading, I get Syntax Error "None of these files exist"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

I am trying to insert a custom font into React Native Expo. I am using the AppLoading method. For some reason, I get an error message saying "None of these files exist"
[image]
[image]

...even though the file clearly does exist in the file directory:
[image]

My Expo version is 5.4.0. I've looked for similar questions, but they either don't involve fonts, or they are using font Async rather than AppLoading.

This is my full code below.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen'; 

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { Font } from 'expo'; 

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


export default function App() {
  
  
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'SEGOEUI': require('./assets/fonts/SEGOEUI.TTF'),
    }); 

    if (!fontsLoaded) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }
   

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} /> 
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the file extension type of the font file you are trying to load to the `metro.config.js` file

should look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
   transformer: {
      assetPlugins: ["expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles"],
   },
   resolver: {
      assetExts: [
         "db",
         "mp3",
         "ttf", //<-- this is the one you want
         "obj",
         "png",
         "jpg",
         "jpeg",
         "mp4",
         "jfif",
         "otf",
      ],
   },
};
```